# What is the correct "Go way" for having a type that has required members and interface?

Tags: go, interface, structure, implementation

An issue I came across designing a Window that is platform independent for a graphics software. I require each window implements a Launch() function, and has a size.

My current solution is a struct called BaseWindow that has Size embedded and an interface called Window with Launch() and GetSize(). An OpenGLWindow for example will then embed BaseWindow and implement Launch() using openGL calls. I feel this isn't correct because of a few code smells.
A) I don't like it having to be called GetSize(). But if I call it Size() it conflicts with the Size field of the embedded size struct in BaseWindow.
B) Interfaces should be implementation independent, but these getters are pretty close to forcing implementation.

I would like in the end to have a single type Window to pass around and use without worrying about the implementation of which platform it's on.

```golang
// What I have
type Size struct {
  Width int
  Height int
}

// What I would like to be my type that I use to access these functions/members
type Window interface {
  GetSize() Size
  Launch() error
}

// This would have more things in the final application, but for simplicity
// I only included Size
type BaseWindow struct {
  Size
}

// Example of what I want my end result to look like
type OpenGLWindow {
  BaseWindow
}

func (window OpenGLWindow) Launch() {
  // Do stuff
}

// Notice Window returns size of BaseWindow and uses Launch of OpenGLWindow
func SetGlobalWin(window Window) {
  GlobalWin = window
  CirclePositionX = window.GetSize().Width / 2
  window.Launch()
}

// If using openGL, open openGL window and use that as primary window
func UseMyWindow() {
  glwin := NewOpenGLWindow()
  SetGlobalWin(glwin)
}
```

While this approach works, it doesn't seem like a good solution for reasons stated above. I have a feeling I'm trying too hard to make Launch() act like a virtual function from oop and am missing some fundamental design patterns for Go's more composition based approach.

Comment: Depends on... if you just have a OpenGLWindow, there is no need to define a interface and a BaseWindow. Just implement the type OpenGLWindow and write some tests, then you can refactor your app if you would need a QTWindow later.

Comment: @apxp I require swapping implementations. For example I'd like DirectX Support as well. Ideally my application just interfaces with a common API and properties, but the implementation under the hood can be swapped for DirectX, Metal, OpenGL, etc

Comment: In Go the caller should define the interface. So first you should write the function which uses your Window and then you should create the interface. Now you are thinking about the interface first. Now you are thinking about Launch() first. I think you should first implement everything for OpenGLWindow and then abstract everything.
I would also remove the BaseWindow type. You can embed the size directly into OpenGLWindow.

Comment: @apxp thanks for your response. In my actual case BaseWindow type has several fields (4 or 5) and could have more moving forward. Thus why I wanted to put it all into one easily embedable type. That way if that basic structure changes, I don't have to go to all my specific window types and change the structure for each one. I could instead change the BaseWindow struct. Do you feel I'm still incorrect for doing this?